# How to verify in selenium if the image is shown on the page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify if a particular image is shown on page with selenium in python. HTML code looks like this when the image is displayed in a table cell:

```
<td role="gridcell">
<div style="text-align: center">
<img class="grid-center-image" border="0" ng-show="dataItem.device_protected" src="resources/images/icon_supported.png"/>
</div>
</td>
```

When the image is not displayed it looks like:

```
<td role="gridcell">
<div style="text-align: center">
<img class="grid-center-image ng-hide" border="0" ng-show="dataItem.device_protected" src="resources/images/icon_supported.png"/>
</div>
</td>
```

I do not understand how to approach this? How do I verify if the image is present on the screen?

Comment: You have to put a check on class attribute. If ng-hide is present in class attribute then image will not be visible and vice versa. See my below answer to understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out if the image `icon_supported.png` is hidden with a single call:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img[src$='icon_supported.png'].ng-hide") :
    print "image hidden"
else :
    print "image displayed"
```

Comment: I was able to do it with css_selector and giving img src and class paramaters to it

Comment: My bad, I changed the `ng-hide` to a class instead of an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get class attribute of your img tag and then have to check that whether 'ng-hide' is present in it or not. That'll decide the presence of image on screen.

Below is the sample code in python to check visibility of image on screen.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//your/xpath/to/img/tag')
if 'ng-hide' in elem.get_attribute('class'):
    print 'Image is not visible on screen'
else:
    print 'Image is visible on screen'
```